# Two connected divs with irregular shapes - images with text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am looking to reproduce this kind of shapes on both connected divs.

[Skewed divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUIMD.jpg)

Both of the divs supposed to be skewed, but text inside should be normal and exactly in the middle of the element.

The one issue is, I cannot find a way to how you can connect them with the support for IE11 without using clip-path.

I would like to make it supportable to IE11(so clip-path is not a way) and responsive.

This is my example on codepen:

```css
.hello {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 65%;
    height: 850px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .part1 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 0;
  }

  .part2 {
    right: 0;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }

  a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hello">
      <div class="part1">
        <a href="#"><h2>text</h2></a>
            <svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip1">
                  <polygon points="0 0, 10 -1, 4 10, 0 10" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
                <image xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1042168/pexels-photo-1042168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#clip1)"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="part2">
          <a href="#"><h2>text</h2></a>
            <svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip2">
                  <polygon points="6.5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 1.5 10" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
                <image xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/745407/pexels-photo-745407.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#clip2)"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Anyone who can help I really appreciate!
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code - what worked for you and how it failed, etc.....

Comment: @CFPSupport thank you for you comment, this is an example on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJoLvP

Comment: @TemaniAfif hi Temani, sorry if have taken this personal, my requirement meant that I have been told to make it workable with IE11, sorry if you have been affected and felt wrong, here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJoLvP

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry and, code added, I did not mean to be mean..